# Is there a way to prevent chrome access to IndexedDB?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, indexeddb, chrome-debugging

Is there a way to prevent google chrome access to IndexedDB ?

Want it for testing errors while writing to IndexedDB...

Comment: Try running `chrome --disable-databases` custom command line.

Comment: Not worked... it still manage to write to IndexedDB.

Comment: Make sure to use "Exit" command in Chrome's menu. And verify you've specified the command line correctly on `chrome://version` page.

Comment: I got windows, i didn't found it. thx. https://superuser.com/a/299080/1081207 worked for me- but disabled all cookies as well...

Comment: Sounds like you didn't specify the command line correctly. Look for tutorials on doing that in Windows.